# Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) Implementation

Tags: python, dfa

I need to build a state machine and write a control program to recognise a set of strings of zeros and ones, in which there are three zeros between each occurrence of one. Below is my code which is not working correctly. I will be grateful for the advice

```
Z = ["0", "1"]
Q = ["A", "B"]
S = "A"
F = "B"

def delta(s, z):
    i = Q.index(s)
    j = Z.index(z)
    matrix = [["A", "B"], ["B", "A"]]
    return matrix[i][j]

chain = "1000110110101"
transitions = ""

for char in range(len(chain)):
    if char == 0:
        transitions += S
        s = delta(S, chain[char])
    else:
        s = delta(s, chain[char])
    transitions += s

if transitions != "":
    print("The sequence of transitions of a finite automaton:", transitions)
    if transitions[-1] == F:
        print("Chain ", chain, "is allowed automaton, because the latter is the allowable state ", F)
    else:
        print("Chain ", chain, " is rejected by the automaton, so its final state is an inadmissible state", S)
else:
    print("The chain is empty.")
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working correctly? Can you describe the specific issues you've run into?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have been introduced to classes yet but I would definitely recommend using them for DFAs.

```
class binaryNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.zero = self
        self.one = self
        self.isAccept = True
    def process(self,char):
        if char == "0":
            return self.zero
        if char == "1":
            return self.one

#Define Nodes
start = binaryNode()
one = binaryNode()
firstZero = binaryNode()
secondZero = binaryNode()
thirdZero = binaryNode()
trailingZero = binaryNode()
reject = binaryNode()

#Define Edges
start.one = one
one.one = reject
one.zero = firstZero
firstZero.zero = secondZero
firstZero.one = reject
secondZero.zero = thirdZero
secondZero.one = reject
thirdZero.one = one
thirdZero.zero = trailingZero
trailingZero.one = reject

#Set Accept (or in this case reject) state
reject.isAccept = False

def process(chain,node):
    for char in chain:
        node = node.process(char)
    return node.isAccept

tests = ["0000",
         "01000100",
         "0100010001000100",
         "0100001",
         "100101",
         "10001",
         "10000"]

for chain in tests:
    print(chain)
    print(process(chain,start))
    print()
```

I interpreted your "recognize a set of strings of zeros and ones, in which there are three zeros between each occurrence of one" with a focus on between so 100000000 passes and so does 100 because there is no second 1 to satisfy the "between" aspect but perhaps I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Yes, I need to put three 0s after each 1. Example input: 1010010 - output: 100010001000

Comment: That's not what your question says.